# How to replicate Apache redirect regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a site that has an Apache redirect. I need to replicate this regex in Java to scrub some URL's from the same server.

This is Apache redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://example.com/$4
```

How do I use this in Java so I can do something like this, so it will adjust the string if it needs to or leave it alone if it doesn't match?:

```
String url = "http://example.com/2012/04/06/somepage"
url.replaceAll(?, ?); // Result should be: http://example.com/somepage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, your regex doesn't contain any character that need to be escaped in java.

---

However, a difference is that in the conf file you don't have the protocol and server name for the origin. Hence, you should just remove the `^` at the start. Also you just replace part of the string, you don't completely rewrite it, therefore you should omit the protocol and server name in the replacements expression:

```
url.replaceAll("/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$", "/$4");
```

---

Or if you want to be extra explicit you can add them in both places:

```
url.replaceAll("^https?://example.com/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$", "http://example.com/$4");
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearer regex:

```
url.replaceFirst("\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}/", "")
```